# Как рисовать много объектов без потери производительности? Java

Tags: java, разработка-игр, оптимизация, libgdx

Всем привет, я начинающий developer пишущий разные игры и приложения на java (практикуюсь, нарабатываю навыки). Меня давно преследует проблема рисования большого количества объектов. Все они сильно тормозят игровой процесс, даже если не обновляются, я конечно понимаю, что метод перерисовки играет и роль обновления, но если вызывать метод отрисовки только при создании объекта, он сразу перекрывается фоном приложения, который стирает всю остаточную мишуру. Но ведь люди как-то это делают - ниже будет пример. В данном примере объекты не просто лежат на поле, но и имеют свой hit-box судя по всему, так как при коллизии с ними, игрок оставляет след. Я бы хотел достичь примерно такого результата, и прошу всех кто знаком с данной проблемой поделится материалом или своим опытом. Возможно моя проблема заключается в самом алгоритме отрисовки, но так как я новичок, как сделать лучше пока не знаю. Буду очень признателен! 
На данный момент стараюсь разобраться в libGDX, с целью поиска большей оптимизации, но видимо проблема кроется во мне... 
[image: Ожидаемый результат]

Comment: Вы спрайты батчите? https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-Textureregions,-and-Sprites

Comment: Нет, не сталкивался с этим. Да и не совсем понимаю суть батчинга спрайтов, если не сложно, прошу объяснить на пальцах.

Comment: Окей, я немного вник. Но какая разница между спрайтами и графическими примитивами, особенно если объект простой до невозможности и удобнее использовать второе.*Разумеется в плане оптимизации

Comment: Это я как пример привёл. Пока вы не узнаете, где именно просадка, предметно говорить сложно. Что там в профайлере?

Comment: Съедается огромное количество оперативки, как-будто запустил какой-то AAA проект. Опять-же скорее всего причина в моем коде. Я использую массив для всех игровых объектов, и к примеру такие простые объекты в виде эффектов или плитки на полу также входят туда, а обрабатывать тысячи объектов java не в кайф. Просто как иначе сделать до меня не доходит, я не спорю можно не обновлять объекты выходящие за поле зрения игрока, но если они все в одной точке, то что делать?

Comment: Объекты памяти почти не жрут. Память жрут ресурсы. Если вы не батчите спрайты, а создаёте копии на каждый объект, то, к примеру, если у вас тысяча объектов, то в 1000 раз больше памяти будет съедаться на эту текстуру.

Comment: В каком плане батчинг текстур? Я храню спрайты в отдельном классе и оттуда уже их достаю, загружая в класс.

Answer (score 1):

Как рисовать много объектов без потери производительности?

## Общие техники оптимизации

При отрисовке кадра в очень много времени занимает вызов функции отрисовки. Поэтому первое что делаю для ускорение графические движки - бачинг. Бачинг - это процесс группировки объектов которые могут быть отрисованы в один подход. Например, в системе частиц вместо того чтобы рисовать сотни квадратов по одному за раз создают одну сетку полигонов и рисуют за один подход все сразу. Бачинг всех объектов, как правило, не возможен. Самый простой бачинг можно сделать так: отсортировать все объекты по глубине, сгруппировать по материалу (шейдер+текстуры), посчитать финальное положение всех сеток в текущей камере, соединить все сетки в одну. Это динамический бачинг. Есть ещё статический когда, например, в 3д сцене детали ландшафта соединяют в одну большую сетку.
Вообще я каждый раз удивляюсь насколько быстрее все работает когда включаешь бачинг.

Чтобы улучшить бачинг нужно использовать атласы - одна большая текстура со множеством маленьких текстур. Это позволит сгруппировать больше объектов. Есть случаи когда генерируют шейдер который использует одновременно несколько атласов динамически выбирая правильный для правильного объекта.

Вторая техника для оптимизации рендера - отбраковка. Тут есть несколько элементов. Отбраковка поверхностей, которые не направлены в камеру (в основном для 3Д) - back face culling. Отбраковка объектов, находящихся за пределами пирамиды обзора - view frustum culling. И в помощь ей - замощение (тесселяция) объектов, находящихся частично в пирамиде.

Для эффективного рендера текстур нужно чтобы пиксели текстуры максимально совпадали с пикселями буфера в который они будут рисоваться (масштаб 1:1). Это еще и улучшит качество финальной картинки.

## Оптимизация в частных случаях

Первое, что нужно сделать при оптимизации, - понять что именно нужно оптимизировать. Для этого используют профайлер. Профайлер покажет сколько времени занимает каждая часть кода. После этого можно заняться оптимизацией кода. Ещё очень важно понимать где проблема имплементации, а где - алгоритма. Про оптимизацию каждого конкретного случая лучше спрашивать отдельно.